# How to include borders in a sort?

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:**
Is there a way to sort in MS Excel VBA, where cell borders are moved with values as they are sorted?

**Details:**

- I don't see anything in the documentation that would indicate how to do this.
- I'd like to avoid appending anything to cells or code to indicate what it's border should be.  I could create a separate method that looks at every cell after a sort and applies the border to the correct cell, but I'd like to avoid this. In other words, once a border is set, it needs to move with a cell's value during sorting.
- I'm using Excel 2007 on a Win7 machine.

**Code / Example:**
For example, take the simple procedure:

```
Public Sub sort_test()
'declare key range and range to sort
Dim range_keyRange As Range
Dim range_fullRange As Range

'key range is column A, rows 1 through 5
Set range_keyRange = Range("A1:A5")

'full range is the used range of the active sheet
Set range_fullRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

'clear previous sortfields
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear

'set sortfields
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add _
  Key:=range_keyRange, _
  SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
  Order:=xlAscending, _
  DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

'apply sort
With ActiveSheet.Sort
  .SetRange range_fullRange
  .Header = xlNo
  .MatchCase = False
  .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

I create the following table, with a border around the cell containing "1"...

2  b
4  d
1  a
3  c
5  e

...when I sort, the result is this, with a border around the cell containing "3":
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e

The border remains in the same position. How can I make the border "move" with the cell during the sort?

My actual sort procedure is more complex, and deals with greater data than shown here.

Comment: unfortunately I'm thinking there is no way to do this. It appears that borders are not moved when sorting and I can't see any way to do this either. though could you provide more detail on how the borders come to be? how are yuo putting them in (code or manually?) and how is it decided which cells get borders? is there an algorithm behind it?

Comment: further to my comment I found this: "http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/Formatting/30503.html" which confirms my thinking that cells are not sorted but the data within.

Comment: @user1759942 In the example in this question, the border was manually added. But in real life, there is an algorithm. A border is applied around a cell to emphasize that a change has not occurred over a length of time. After the border is applied, the column containing that value may be sorted many times before the algorithm checks for change again.

Comment: And, I noticed other aspects of the cell could be sorted besides the data. Ref the SortField.SortOn property. In Excel 2007 at least, cell color, font color, icon, and values can all be the basis for the sort... not exactly helpful with what I'm asking here, but useful additional info.

Comment: added answer, lemme know how it works, I'll check later

Answer (score 0):

This would be a kind of "Hack" if you will... (not really but w/e)

You could accomplish this with a VBA macro and "Helper" columns.

Basically, add extra columns before sorting, 1 for each column that contains cells with borders. (so if 3 out of 10 columns have cells with borders, you'd add 3 columns. I would name them for example "colBBorders" "ColFborders" etc.. )

have a macro put an x on each row in the helper column when it's reference column has a border.

So for example if you had columns A - F with columns b and d having cells with borders, and lets say, rows 1,3,5 have borders in B and rows 2,4,6 have borders in D. in the first helper column (maybe it's name is "ColBBorders") the macro would put x's on rows 1,3,5 and in the second helper column (maybe it's header is ColDBorders) the macro would place x's on rows 2,4,6

then, after sorting, have another macro that A) reomves all borders (maybe that's easier done manually) and then puts borders around each cell in the appropriate reference column (b, or D) when its helper column (colbborders, colDBorders) has an x on that row.

if you give the helpers standard names, you could evwen use for example `left(cells(1, 7).value, 4)` if column 7 had the header "colbborders" then that code would get you the letter "B" which you could use to identify the referenced column.

Comment: Thanks for the input - unfortunately goes against point #2 in the "details" portion of the question. But I agree with you, this is the only way I know of to do this as well.

Comment: ohhh yes I'm sorry you're right I missed that. But yea, seems the only way to do it as upon googling I found mu;tiple sources that say that cells are not moved, only data. I confirmed this by testing, everything IN a cell moves, color, fill, all that.. but not the borders. could you use a fill or font instead of border?

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of an earlier development, a couple of years ago, I customized a "Quicksort" method so as to make possible quick-sorting for a multi-column table.
For your purpose, I customized the "Permutation" part of this routine. It relies on 'copy' method, therefore it will not be quick on "big" multi-column tables.
This code does not meet some part of point #2 because the code is changed but I hope that you'll find the multi-column possibility useful.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Option Base 1

Dim iRowFirst As Long, iRowLast As Long
Dim iBas As Long, iHaut As Long, iRowMid As Long
Dim sVarMid As String

Public Sub sort_test()

    'declare table
    Dim MCTable() As Variant

    'declare key range and range to sort
    Dim range_keyRange As Range

    'key range is column A, rows 1 through 5
    Set range_keyRange = Range("A1:A5")
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ToSort", RefersTo:="=" & range_keyRange.Address

    ' call "Temp" any cell not used
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Temp", RefersTo:="=$C$1"

    MCTable() = Range("ToSort").Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' call QuickSort1(Table which contains the values, # of the column sort key, "asce" or "desc")
    Call QuickSort1(MCTable, 1, "desc")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set range_keyRange = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub QuickSort1(ByRef vList, iColK1 As Long, Sens As String, _
                      Optional ByVal pRowLeft As Long, Optional ByVal pRowRight As Long)

' iColK1 is the number of the column key for sorting.

    iBas = LBound(vList, 2): iHaut = UBound(vList, 2)

    If pRowRight = 0 Then
        pRowLeft = LBound(vList, 1)
        pRowRight = UBound(vList, 1)
    End If

    iRowFirst = pRowLeft
    iRowLast = pRowRight

    iRowMid = (pRowLeft + pRowRight) \ 2
    sVarMid = vList(iRowMid, iColK1)

    Do
'=====================================================================================
'   Comparaison
'=====================================================================================
        If LCase(Sens) Like "asce" Then

            Do While sVarMid > vList(iRowFirst, iColK1) And iRowFirst < pRowRight
                iRowFirst = iRowFirst + 1
            Loop

            Do While vList(iRowLast, iColK1) > sVarMid And iRowLast > pRowLeft
                iRowLast = iRowLast - 1
            Loop

        ElseIf LCase(Sens) Like "desc" Then

            Do While vList(iRowFirst, iColK1) > sVarMid And iRowFirst < pRowRight
                iRowFirst = iRowFirst + 1
            Loop

            Do While sVarMid > vList(iRowLast, iColK1) And iRowLast > pRowLeft
                iRowLast = iRowLast - 1
            Loop

        End If
'=====================================================================================
'       Permutation
'=====================================================================================
        If iRowFirst <= iRowLast Then

            ' Echange de positions
            Call MoveRow(vList, iRowFirst, iRowLast, iBas, iHaut)

            iRowFirst = iRowFirst + 1
            iRowLast = iRowLast - 1

        End If
'=====================================================================================

    Loop Until iRowFirst > iRowLast

    If pRowLeft < iRowLast Then QuickSort1 vList, iColK1, Sens, pRowLeft, iRowLast
    If iRowFirst < pRowRight Then QuickSort1 vList, iColK1, Sens, iRowFirst, pRowRight

End Sub

Sub MoveRow(ByRef aList, iSour As Long, iDest As Long, iBas As Long, iHaut As Long)

Dim Temp() As String
Dim rTem As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim bGo As Boolean

    For i = iBas To iHaut
        ReDim Preserve Temp(i)

        Range("ToSort")(iDest, i).Copy Range("Temp")
        Temp(i) = aList(iDest, i)

        Range("ToSort")(iSour, i).Copy Range("ToSort")(iDest, i)
        aList(iDest, i) = aList(iSour, i)

        Range("Temp").Copy Range("ToSort")(iSour, i)
        aList(iSour, i) = Temp(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

For 10++ columns,  helper columns not efficient.  In the real world,  not all actions maybe turn into an algorithm.  For example,  two cells the value,  format,  etc.  everything is the same as each other but one of them is border as supporting received. 
We may use VBA to do the sorting (not the Excel default method in VBA).  The question is how the VBA code is designed.

Comment: it's obvious some thought has gone into this, but downvoting as this would be more appropriate as either a concrete answer, or a comment on an existing answer.